# Nomad gitlab with consul

Tags: docker, gitlab, consul, nomad

I try to have a gitlab job on my nomad cluster and to get it with a Consul's address.
My gitlab job:

```
    job "gitlabce2" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]  group "echo" {
    count = 1
    task "server" {

      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "gitlab/gitlab-ce"
        args  = []
      }      
    resources {
        memory = 2500
        cpu = 3000
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "http" {}
      }
    }
    service {
        name = "gitlabce"
        port = "http"

        tags = [
          "mypc",
          "urlprefix-/gitlabce2",
        ]        
        
        check {
          type     = "http"
          path     = "/"
          interval = "2s"
          timeout  = "2s"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But Consul see my job but apparently my job is not on the good port. When I go inside the container I can do a curl localhost:80, but else I cannot have access to my gitlab.

How can I configure my job file ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Nomad 0.12 deprecated the `mbits` field in the `network` block, as well as the placement of the `network` block under `resources` (https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/upgrade/upgrade-specific#mbits-and-task-network-resource-deprecation).

Port allocations are now defined under *group -> network*, and then mapped to a container under *group -> task -> config -> ports*.

See https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/network#mapped-ports for details.

The following modified job spec will correctly have Nomad map an automatically assigned external port to port 80 of the running container.

```
job "gitlabce2" {
  datacenters = ["dc2"]

  group "echo" {
    count = 1

    network {
      port "http" {
        to = 80
      }
    }

    task "server" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "gitlab/gitlab-ce"
        args  = []
        ports = ["http"]
      }

      resources {
        memory = 2500
        cpu = 3000
      }

      service {
        name = "gitlabce"
        port = "http"

        tags = [
          "mypc",
          "urlprefix-/gitlabce2",
        ]        
        
        check {
          type     = "http"
          path     = "/"
          interval = "2s"
          timeout  = "2s"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```